# Powershell Chinese characters encoding error

Tags: powershell, encoding, character-encoding

I have a file called `test.txt` which contains a single Chinese character, `中`, in it.

This character looks like this

[image]

under hex-editor's view.

If I do `get-content test.txt | Out-File test_output.txt`, the content of `test_output.txt` is different from `test.txt`. Why is this hapenning?

I've tried all the encoding parameters listed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/4.0/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file#-encoding) ("Unicode", "UTF7", "UTF8", "UTF32", "ASCII", "BigEndianUnicode", "Default", and "OEM"), but none of them correctly converts the Chinese character.

How can I correctly convert Chinese characters using `Get-Content` and `Out-File`?

The encoding, `e4 b8 ad`, looks like [URLencode](http://www.url-encode-decode.com/) of `中`, is this why all the encoding parameters are not compatible with this Chinese character?

I use [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and Notepad++'s [hex-editor plugin](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/Hex%20Editor/) as my text-editor and hex-editor, respectively.

Comment: What encoding is used in the file itself? That is, what [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) are there?

Comment: The encoding is UTF-8 without BOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried `get-content test.txt -encoding UTF8 | Out-File test_output.txt -encoding UTF8`

My `test.txt` is "**e4 b8 ad** 0a". And the output is "ef bb bf **e4 b8 ad** 0d 0a"

`test.txt` is in UTF-8.

`Get-Content` doesn't recognize UTF-8 unless with BOM. `Out-File` uses UTF-16 by default.

So specifying encoding for both commands is necessary

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the **Unicode** encoding solved my problem with the Chinese characters. The file I was modifying contained a C# code on a TFS sever.

```
$path="test.cs"
Get-Content -Path $path -Encoding Unicode
Set-Content -Path $path -Encoding Unicode
```

it might help somebody else.